# c++ Hangman game project help how to find a letter in a string

Tags: c++

Hi I started c++ lot too long ago in my programming class and our teacher gave us a project to work on. It's a hangman game with pretty specific requirements. I started it, but I'm stuck at the part that checks if the inputted letter is in the word.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int errorNb;
string Player1;
string Player2;
string UnknownWord;
string secretWord;
char letter;
int alive(1);

void displayUnknownWord(string UnknownWord)
{
    for (int a(0); a<=secretWord.size(); a++)
    {
        if (secretWord[a] == letter)
        {
            UnknownWord[a+a]=letter;
        }
    }
    cout << "The secret word is: " << UnknownWord << endl;
}

void displayHangman(int errorNb)
{
    if (errorNb == 0)
    {
        cout << endl << endl
            <<" _____       "<< endl
            <<"|     |      "<< endl
            <<"|            "<< endl
            <<"|            "<< endl
            <<"|            "<< endl
            <<"|____________"<< endl<< endl;
    }
    else if (errorNb == 1)
    {
       cout << endl << endl
            <<" _____       "<< endl
            <<"|     |      "<< endl
            <<"|     O      "<< endl
            <<"|            "<< endl
            <<"|            "<< endl
            <<"|____________"<< endl<< endl;
    }
    else if (errorNb == 2)
    {
       cout << endl << endl
            <<" _____       "<< endl
            <<"|     |      "<< endl
            <<"|     O      "<< endl
            <<"|     |      "<< endl
            <<"|            "<< endl
            <<"|____________"<< endl<< endl;
    }
    else if (errorNb == 3)
    {
       cout << endl << endl
            <<" _____       "<< endl
            <<"|     |      "<< endl
            <<"|    _O      "<< endl
            <<"|     |      "<< endl
            <<"|            "<< endl
            <<"|____________"<< endl<< endl;
    }
    else if (errorNb == 4)
    {
       cout << endl << endl
            <<" _____       "<< endl
            <<"|     |      "<< endl
            <<"|    _O_     "<< endl
            <<"|     |      "<< endl
            <<"|            "<< endl
            <<"|____________"<< endl<< endl;
    }
    else if (errorNb == 5)
    {
       cout << endl << endl
            <<" _____       "<< endl
            <<"|     |      "<< endl
            <<"|    _O_     "<< endl
            <<"|     |      "<< endl
            <<"|    /       "<< endl
            <<"|____________"<< endl<< endl;
    }
    else if (errorNb == 5)
    {
       cout << endl << endl
            <<" _____       "<< endl
            <<"|     |      "<< endl
            <<"|    _O_     "<< endl
            <<"|     |      "<< endl
            <<"|    / \\     "<< endl
            <<"|____________"<< endl<< endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to HANGMAN!" << endl <<endl << "Player 1, enter your name." 
         << endl;
    cin >> Player1;
    cout << "Player 2, enter your name." <<endl;
    cin >> Player2;

    cout << endl << Player1 << ". Please choose a secret word. "
            "(Use lower case only)" <<endl;
    cin >> secretWord;

    for (int i(0); i< secretWord.size(); ++i)
    {
        UnknownWord += "_ ";
    }

    for (int s(0);s<30; ++s)
    {
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "GAME START" << endl <<endl;
    displayUnknownWord(UnknownWord);
    displayHangman(errorNb);

    while (alive = 1)
    {
        cout << Player2 << endl << "Please guess a letter (lower case only):" << endl;
        cin >> letter;

        if (secretWord.find(letter))
        {
            cout << "CORRECT!" << endl;
            displayUnknownWord(UnknownWord);
            displayHangman(errorNb);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "WRONG!" << endl;
            ++errorNb;
            displayUnknownWord(UnknownWord);
            displayHangman(errorNb);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and here are the instructions that the teacher gave us:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki4Ja.png)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please include the error message also, or at least a description of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the find() method properly like this:

```
if (secretWord.find(letter) != std::string::npos)
    ;// find
else
    ;// not find
```

But you are far from being done. For instance, you do not store the already correctly guessed letters.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This helped me a lot. For the already correctly guessed letters, would it be better to store them as a string of letters, adding a new one when it is guessed or would it be better to store them another way?

Comment: Actually, I would use an array. So you can easily fill the blanks when a new letter was guessed. But it's up to you. Fee free to accept and upvote.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a bit confused as to what I should be storing into an array and where. I feel like what I want to try and do is turn the UnknownWord into an array of _, then replace each of the _ with the correctly guessed letters. I just don't know if I should do this in the displayUnknownWord or in the main.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple answer to this is to use `std::find` or just iterate through the array.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah because [`string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) is such a hassle